# Tax rate cannot be removed. It exists in tax rule

Tags: magento-1.8

I am getting this error when i going to remove first 3 tax rules

can you please tell me how i can remove them.its very urgent issue to fix its magento 1.9.

i have already tying to remove it but Tax rate cannot be removed. It exists in tax rule is the error showing Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Open your tax rules and deselect the tax rates you want to remove. The tax rates should not be assigend to a tax rule if you want to delete them.